# setattribute value to be fetch in jsp by getattribute but getting nullpointer

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I had tried from servlet set value by setattribute and it have to iterate in jsp by getattribute by setter and getter method without EL and JSTl but am getting this error .kindly help on this i searched in google but i cant found.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.jsp.Home_jsp._jspService(Home_jsp.java:138)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

here serlvet code

```
    package servlet2;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import javafx.css.PseudoClass;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import servlet.Dao;
import jdbc.jdbcconnection;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Homepage
 */
//@WebServlet(asyncSupported = true, urlPatterns = { "/Homepage" })
public class Homepage extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Homepage() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }




    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.out.println("inside==========>");

        String name=request.getParameter("name");
        String password=request.getParameter("password");
        String phone=request.getParameter("Phone");
        String Deptmart=request.getParameter("Dep");
        String gender=request.getParameter("gender");
        String country=request.getParameter("country");

        Dao d=new Dao();

        try
        {
        jdbcconnection jc=new jdbcconnection();

        Connection con=jc.getconnection();

        String sql="insert into homepage(name,password,phone,Dept,gender,Country) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";

            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement(sql);

            ps.setString(1, name);
            ps.setString(2, password);
            ps.setString(3, phone);
            ps.setString(4, Deptmart);
            ps.setString(5, gender);
            ps.setString(6, country);

            System.out.println("ps=========>"+ps);

            ps.execute();

            con.commit();


            String select="select * from homepage";

            PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement(select);

            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();

            ArrayList t=new ArrayList();
            while(rs.next())
            {
                d.setid(rs.getInt(1));
                d.setName(rs.getString(2));
                d.setPassword(rs.getString(3));
                d.setPhone(rs.getInt(4));
                d.setDeptmart(rs.getString(5));
                d.setGender(rs.getString(6));
                d.setCountry(rs.getString(7));

                t.add(d);
            }

            request.setAttribute("users",t);

            RequestDispatcher rs1=request.getRequestDispatcher("/Home.jsp");
            rs1.forward(request, response);
                }

        catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Jsp page:

```
<%@page import="servlet.Dao,java.util.*" %>




<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="Homepage" method="get">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="name" id="name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="password" id="password"></td>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone">
        </tr>
        </td>
        <tr>
            <td>Department:</td>
            <td><select id="Dep" name="Dep">
                    <option value="it">IT</option>
                    <option value="finace">Finace</option>
                    <option value="market">Marketing</option>
            </select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Gender:</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" Value="Male">Male
                <input type="radio" name="gender" id="gender" Value="Female">Female</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>Country:</td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="country" id="country"
                Value="India">India <input type="checkbox" name="country"
                id="country" Value="Other">Other</td>
        </tr>

        <br>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Add" Value="ADD" ></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="Clear" Value="CLEAR"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>

<table border="1">

<tr><td>Id</td><td>name</td>
<td>Password</td>
<td>Phone</td>
<td>Deptmart</td>
<td>Gender</td>
<td>country</td>
<td>Edit</td>
<td>Delete</td>
</tr>

 <%
 try
 {
        List<Dao> al1 = (List) request.getAttribute("users");
      //  System.out.println(al1); // prints null
        for(Dao user : al1) {



        %>

<tr>
<td><%=user.getid() %></td>

<td><%=user.getName() %></td>
<td><%=user.getPassword() %></td>
<td><%=user.getPhone() %></td>
<td><%=user.getDeptmart() %></td>
<td><%=user.getGender() %></td>
<td><%=user.getCountry() %></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<%} }

 catch(Exception e)
 {
    e.printStackTrace();  
 }
%>




</table>


</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Homepage</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlet2.Homepage</servlet-class>
  </servlet>



  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Homepage</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Homepage</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Did you step through the code using debug to see if the servlet method is getting executed? I don't see anything wrong which might cause the issue.

Comment: if i tried to debug am getting nullpointer exception i cant processed to debug itself

Comment: So are you accessing the servlet or jsp directly?

Comment: am trying to access servlet directly

Comment: is there any other way to get value from servlet to jsp

Comment: Can you post your servlet method completely and the url that you are accessing?

Comment: ya updated my coding..

Comment: keep null checks, to avoid NullpointerException. Hint: put a breakpoint at `ArrayList t=new ArrayList();` and check if rs has any rows? And always you will get one `Dao` object only.

Comment: Post the URL that you are trying to hit?